# Get unrelated record to model

Tags: django, django-models

Lets say i have 2 models. That has no FK relation but both have a common relationship 'em'. Is there a way to get through queryset the A model and the latest B record connecting it with 'em' relationship ?. Maybe with subqueries?. Result to be like:

```
A = {
  'name':'Test',
  'B': {
    em: 15,
    date: '2020/02/22'  
  }
}

class A(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
   em = models.ForeignKey('em')

class B(models.Model):
   date_created=models.DateField()
   em = models.ForeignKey('em')

class em(models.Model):
   id = models.CharField()
```

Comment: Just to clarify, given a model A object (or vice versa) you want to find the model B object that has the same 'em' foreign key value?

Answer (score 0):

You can access `B` objects from `A` by doing something like this  :

```
related_b_objects = a.em.b_set.all()
```